# Issues with replacing CSS tags with gsub

Tags: r, web-scraping, gsub

I am currently working on a web scraping project. My current problem is removing CSS tags from my data. Here are the basics of my code:

```
library(Rcrawler)
setwd("C:myfile")
Rcrawler(Website = "http://www.soyaquaalliance.com/", no_cores = 4, no_conn = 4, ExtractCSSPat = c("div"))
test1<-gsub("[\\t\\n]"," ",DATA) print(test1)
```

If you check the console you'll notice that gsub replaces the CSS tags but it also replaces all ts and ns in the text my code is scraping. How can I effectively remove the CSS tags without impacting the other text?

Answer (score -1):

Use double backslash. You need to escape the first backslash.

Comment: Double backslash removes all the tags, which is helpful with what I am trying to accomplish, but it still removes letters from the text I am trying to gather that I do not want removed.